# Is it possible to use the Stripe API with a CouchApp?

Tags: couchdb, stripe-payments, couchapp

I am curious if it is possible to use the Stripe API within a CouchApp.  Normally I would have server side code that has my Stripe API keys where I would do the transactions from.  Since a CouchApp doesn't really have that server side layer I am at a loss as to how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Try stripe.js:

> Stripe.js makes it easy to collect credit card (and other similarly
>   sensitive) details without having the information touch your server

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js

Answer (score 0):

On the back end you'll want to use stripe's node implementation. Refer to link
https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

You could also want to reference firebase implementation of stripe https://zapier.com/zapbook/firebase/stripe/

NOTE: Don't confuse firebase with couchdb. Same concept slight different engines. Firebase is built on top of mongodb, whereas CouchDB has it's own engine and for all intents and purpose intended to be along side pouchDB.

Hope it helps.